# How to set PyQT4 Stylesheet for Matplotlib widget (navBar/canvas)?

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, pyqt4

I have a QMainWindow app consisting of a Menu Bar, Splitter in the central widget, and a status bar.  On the left side of the splitter is a widget containing some controls (list, combo, and button) and on the right is a widget containing a layout of Matplotlib canvas, and NavigationToolBar.

I was able to use QT Stylesheets to set the various background colors of everything ... except the Matplotlib side.  I attempted to use the following but it has no effect.  I also tried setting the NavBar and Canvas stylesheets directly ... but again it didn't work:

```
self.mplFig.setStyleSheet(".QWidget {background-color:   #0ff}")
```

Basically I am trying to turn the background color of the NavToolbar and the border around the canvas to match everything else (Currently cyan so it shows up easy) ...
Any help would be appreciated.  Full code & sample image below:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("qt4agg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class testGUI(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(testGUI, self).__init__(parent)
        self.buildLayout()
        self.buildMenus()        
        self.menuBar()
        self.statusBar()

        ## Style Sheets
        self.splitter.setStyleSheet("QSplitter::handle:horizontal {background-color:   #ccc}")            
        self.controlWidget.setStyleSheet(".QWidget {background-color:   #0ff}")  
        menuStyle = """.QMenuBar {background-color:   #0ff}
            QMenuBar::item {background: transparent} 
            QMenuBar::item:selected {background: #8ff}"""
        self.statusBar().setStyleSheet(".QStatusBar {background-color:   #0ff}")
        self.menuBar().setStyleSheet(menuStyle)
        # .....THIS DOESN"T WORK !! .....
        self.mplFig.setStyleSheet(".QWidget {background-color:   #0ff}")


    def buildLayout(self):
        self.controlWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self) 
        self.plotList  = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
        self.combo  = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Plot')        
        self.combo.addItems(\['1','2','3','4'\]) 
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.plotList)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.controlWidget.setLayout(layout)
        self.mplFig  = MplGrapher()
        self.splitter = QtGui.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.controlWidget) 
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.mplFig) 
        self.setCentralWidget(self.splitter)
        QtGui.QApplication.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create('Plastique'))
    def buildMenus(self):
        openFile = QtGui.QAction('Open', self)
        self.fileMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu('&File')
        self.fileMenu.addAction(openFile)

class MplGrapher(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(MplGrapher, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initFigure()

    def initFigure(self):   
        self.figure = Figure()        
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.navbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self) 
        self.figure.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.navbar)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = testGUI()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: Sample GUI]

Comment: I'm sorry I don't currently have an answer. I also posted on here a while back about a similar issue (wanting to draw a border around an embedded mpl figure) in Qt

I think he issue lies in how Qt interprets the FigureCanvas object - ie. when you define you qss strings to tell Qt how to style them you need to start by telling Qt what type of widget you are adding style options to. My guess is that Qt isn't interpreting the FigureCanvas as the same widget you are adding style strings for

Comment: I'm currently playing around with some minimal gui's to try and find a way to see how pyqt is interpreting the FigureCanvas object. 


You can add the FigureCanvas object to a boxLayout just fine using addWidget() - so its correctly interpreting the FigureCanvas as a Widget. Figuring out what type of widget might shed some light on things. 


The alternative is that there are just no support style sheet strings for the FigureCanvas object

Comment: Also - I found this in the QSS style guide:  [Styleguide](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html)   It specifically mentions that QWidget only supports a minimal set of QSS properties, "background, background-clip and background-origin"  — Thus if Qt is interpreting the FigureCanvas as a generic QWidget, setting background-color will have no effect

Comment: I am not at my Pc now to check.  But I believe on one of my tests I removed the dot before QWidget on the style sheet definition and every widget on in the Gui was set.... Even the buttons and the background of the listing etc.  So it is recognized as a QWidget at least on some level. Ill update this later when possible with the an example.

Comment: Here's a [link] (http://i.imgur.com/muRcmRP.png) to an image of my GUI; I use QDarkStyle (an external library I import) and then set the stylesheet for the entire app via app.setStyleSheet(qdarkstyle.load_stylesheet(pyside=False)) in my main method.

So presumably some of the QSS in the main file for QDarkStyle has the correct properties for making the background dark which in turn affects the Nav Bar.

I was able to set a border around my Canvas by putting the canvas into an HBoxLayout and then the HBox into a GroupBox and then adding a stylesheet for the Groupbox using the property border

Comment: I think that just lead me down the correct path.  I changed the class MplGrapher from QtGui.QWidget to QtGui.QGroupBox.  Then I removed the dot from before QWidget and success! ... I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have a solution thanks to some tips from Maxwell Grady.

I changed the following 2 lines:

```
self.mplFig.setStyleSheet("QWidget {background-color:   #0ff}")
```

Note the lack of a "." before QWidget and

```
class MplGrapher(QtGui.QGroupBox):
```

Picture of GUI after changes.  Now that I can actually set some style properties ... time to make it less ugly.

[image: Sample with colored in borders.]

Comment: I was happy to stumble on this work around but I can't help but feeling it seems like a silly way to go about the solution.

I guess thats a small price to pay though considering Qt is a C++ framework and we're lucky it works at all so closely with Matplotlib.

Glad it seems to be working

Comment: Thanks again.  It does seem to be a bug.  I don't know why when my MplGrapher was a QWidget Class it ignored the stylesheet ... but a QGroupBox works event though it a subclass of widget.  Anyway, I tried QDarkStyle that you mentioned and I like it a lot. So now I am looking at different different Matlplotlib styles to match.

Comment: mpl is getting an overhaul in the near future. mpl 2.0 is going to be essentially the exact same mpl functionality as the current version (1.4 is it?) but they are adding in a really easy way to set new styles - and their will be a ton of built in pre defined styles to choose from.

It will be as simple as saying import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.style.use('ggplot') which will look like the ggplot package from the R language or plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight') which will make your plots look like the ones in the famous 538 political blog ... etc